# Java switch always runs the default code

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, case, default

I'm a beginner at java and I've been working on this as a little perfect. It's supposed to be a simple calculator. I know there are probably better/more efficient ways to do this, but this is not what I'm looking for. I ran into a small issue when using a `switch` to choose what operation will be run. Basically, what happens is that every time I run the code it chooses the right code to run (if the `String` entered is "+", it will add the `double`s), how ever it always seems to afterwards run the `default` code (which prints "Command not recognized."). If I remove the `default` code it works perfectly (of course, that way, if the user enters an unknown command it will give an error) and I could easily do that, but what I really want is a way to have a default code and to know why it isn't working this way.
Please, Help.
Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double v1 = scan.nextDouble();
    double v2;
    double v3;
    scan.nextLine();
    while(1<2){
    String op = scan.nextLine();
    switch(op){
    case "+":
        v2 = scan.nextDouble();
        v1 = v2 + v1;
        System.out.println("="+v1);
        break;
    case "-":
        v2 = scan.nextDouble();
        v1 = v2 - v1;
        System.out.println("="+v1);
        break;
    case "*":
        v2 = scan.nextDouble();
        v1 = v2 * v1;
        System.out.println("="+v1);
        break;
    case "/":
        v2 = scan.nextDouble();
        v1 = v1 / v2;
        System.out.println("="+v1);
        break;
    case "^":
        v2 = scan.nextDouble();
        v3 = v1;
        for(int i = 1;i<v2;i++){
            v1 = v1*v3;
        }
        System.out.println("="+v1);
        break;
    case "%":
        v2 = scan.nextDouble();
        v1 = (v1/100)*v2;
        System.out.println("="+v1);
        break; 
    default:
        System.out.println("Command not recognized.");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The Output is something like this:

```
5
*
5
=25.0
Command not recognized.
```

Comment: Can you post the input as well coorelated to the output?

Comment: the input was the first three lines in the console (5,*,5) The actual output printed by the program art the last two

Comment: What are you trying here: `while(1<2){`?

Comment: @Bubletan infinite loop

Comment: is an infinate loop. but it wont really loop infinately because the program requires the user to input in every loop.

Comment: Have it spit out the value that triggered the default, e.g. `system.out.println('command not recognized: -' + op + '-);`, or whatever it'd be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `scan.next()` instead of `scan.nextLine()` in this line:

```
String op = scan.next();
```

When you do `scan.nextLine()` it consumes the new line character, so `op` gets set to "new line" and the `switch` ends in the default behavior.

Using `scan.next()` you will be able to do this:

```
5
*
5
=25.0
*
2
=50.0
/
25
=2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

add a `break;` after `System.out.println("Command not recognized.");`

To fix it just break out the loop.

```
default:
            System.out.println("Command not recognized.");
            break;
                }
        break;
            }
```

Since your while loop never end it will keep rerun the code.